# How to get a file descriptor for a folder in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

Many `os` methods allow you to specify the file descriptor `dir_fd` of a folder and provide a file path relative to that folder. The example I stumbled on is [`os.symlink(source_path, target_path, *, dir_fd=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.symlink), where I wanted the symlink to be relative. Without providing `dir_fd`, my symlink appears with an absolute path or relative to the cwd.

How do I obtain such a file descriptor? I cannot use the builtin `open()` on a directory (else I could get a file descriptor from the resulting file object).

Answer (score 7):

I found an answer in [this blog](https://ispycode.com/Blog/python/2016-07/How-To-Get-A-Directory-File-Descriptor). Adding it here for prosperity:

```
import os
fd  = os.open( "/tmp", os.O_RDONLY )
print( fd )
```